# postgresql can't load perl module

Tags: perl, postgresql

Iam having problem creating postgresql function in plperl

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zm_json (TEXT, TEXT) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
  use JSON::XS;
  # do something
  return  $json_out;
$$ LANGUAGE plperl;
```

When i want to create function above iam getting

```
ERROR:  creation of Perl function "zm_json" failed: Unable to load JSON/XS.pm into plperl at line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at line 2.
```

JSON::XS is under `/usr/lib/perl5` and perl inside my postgres shows this directory in libs

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zm_perl_directories() RETURNS TEXT AS $$
  return join(':', @INC);
$$ LANGUAGE plperl;

select zm_perl_directories();
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
zm_perl_directories | /etc/perl:/usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1:/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1:/usr/lib/perl5:/usr/share/perl5:/usr/lib/perl/5.10:/usr/share/perl/5.10:/usr/local/lib/site_perl:.
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Dupes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527843/can-you-use-libraries-in-pl-perl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can you use libraries in PL/Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527843/can-you-use-libraries-in-pl-perl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think plperl is using a safer subset of Perl capabilities.

As such, some language builtins are restricted. `use` or `require` is one of those, otherwise it'd allow for arbitrary code execution.

If you don't care about that, feel free to use `PL/Perlu`, which is the unrestricted Perl.