# PERL DBI in PL/PERL in POSTGRESQL

Tags: dbi, plperl

Can I use DBI in a pl/perl function created in Postgresql to select any foreign database?

Im getting the error: Unable to laod DBI.pm into plperl

(I know that there are oracle foreign data wrappers, but I just need to store the resultset of a select statement fired against Oracle, MSSQL or PG and store it in Postgres.)

Here is my function (just with the connect string at the moment):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sel_ora()
 RETURNS VOID AS $$

use DBI;

my $db = DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:DBKUNDEN", "stadl", "sysadm" )

    || die( $DBI::errstr . "\n" );


$$ LANGUAGE plperl;
```

Comment: What's the actual, full error message?

Comment: The error message is:

SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: Unable to load DBI.pm into plperl at line 3
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at line 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can you use libraries in PL/Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527843/can-you-use-libraries-in-pl-perl)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use DBI from within plperl.

Note that for security reasons, plperl restricts access to using perl modules. This is intended for multi-user databases where your postgres users are not trusted.

The solution in plperl is to add a line such as this to your postgresql.conf file:

```
plperl.on_init = 'use DBI;'
```

Then DBI will be available within your plperl functions.  See docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/plperl-under-the-hood.html

Alternatively, **if this security consideration does not apply** in your situation, then you can use **plperlu** (u = unrestricted) instead of plperl.  Then you can use any perl module directly from your plperlu code.